# Dependency inversion principle in JavaScript, mistake or my misunderstanding?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, abstract-class

I found [this](https://blog.wordbot.io/tech/inverting-dependencies-a-javascript-example-of-the-dependency-inversion-principle/) article about DIP in JS and I have a big question about it.

```js
class Database {
  constructor() {
    this.items = [];
  }

  add(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  get(id) {
    return this.items.find((item) => item.id === id);
  }
}

class DatabaseInterface {
  constructor(database) {
    this.database = database;
  }

  add(item) {
    this.database.add(item);
  }

  get(id) {
    return this.database.get(id);
  }
}

class UserController {
  constructor(databaseInterface) {
    this.databaseInterface = databaseInterface;
  }

  createUser(name) {
    const user = { id: Date.now(), name };
    this.databaseInterface.add(user);
    return user;
  }

  getUser(id) {
    return this.databaseInterface.get(id);
  }
}
```

above code is explained as:

> In this fixed example, we have created an interface for the Database class, called DatabaseInterface. The UserController class now depends on the DatabaseInterface abstraction, which is implemented by the Database class. **By using an abstraction, we have inverted the dependency, and now the low-level Database class depends on the high-level DatabaseInterface abstraction.**

I don't understand how the `Database` class depends on `DatabaseInterface`. I think the opposite - that `DatabaseInterface` depends on `Database`, because `DatabaseInterface` uses `Database`. Am I right?

Comment: That article is hogwash. The `DatabaseInterface` function makes no sense. An interface is something abstract, there is no point in implementing a wrapper for an object that does just the same thing. The `DatabaseInterface` should be left out completely, or at best replaced by `function DatabaseInterface(db) { if (typeof db.add != "function" || typeof db.get != "function") throw new TypeError("not a database"); return db; }`. The actual dependency inversion is already achieved by accepting the `Database` instance as an argument to the `UserController` constructor.